# CSS3 Multi-Column list with form input field

Tags: css

I have a CSS3 Multi-Column list with an input field inside that's not positioned properly. 
It should align with the list-item above - even when one change the viewport.

Currently the input form is moving independently from the other list items when the viewport changes.

Is it possible to get the input field positioned so it's vertically aligned with the list item above?

```
<ul class="subnav-links">
  <li class="new-in ">
    <a href="/de/t/new">New In</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sale ">
    <a href="/de/t/sale">Sale</a>
  </li>
  <li class="looks ">
    <a href="/de/pages/best_looks">Looks</a>
  </li>
  <!-- ...more lis omitted-->
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul.subnav-links {
  -moz-column-count: 8;
  -webkit-column-count: 8;
  column-count: 8;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  word-break: keep-all;
}
form {
  float: right;
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b4a7Ldzy/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the maximum width of the form and the input field like this:

```
ul.subnav-links li form, ul.subnav-links li form input{
    max-width:100%;
}
```